# Apache Configuration on a Mac?

Tags: macos, apache

I just bought my first Mac, and I'm trying to set up an apache server. The problem is that I need to configure it like the live server and my work computer (Linux and WinXP, respectively).

Here's the deal. The website's directory is expected to be:

```
/home/web/companysite/public_html/
```

But on a Mac, the /home/ directory is taken. Any advice? Is there a way I can reroute it without changing all of my PHP files and other scripts?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding absolute paths like that into your PHP files?

Comment: In short, the original developer wasn't very smart. I inherited his mess of code. :P

Comment: Well i mean you could configure it to use that as the document but really what you should do is go through and adjust this... its going to need to be done at some point, no doubt.

Comment: True, but I don't have time at the moment and my boss isn't paying me for that. In the mean time, is there a quick way that I can reroute this so when PHP sees include("/home/web/companysite/public_html/") it goes to something like "/somefolder/home/web/companysite/public_html/"? I know there is a way in the HTTPConfig file, but I can't recall how at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I would us a virtual host for this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/home/web/companysite/public_html">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName companysite.local
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot "/home/web/companysite/public_html"
</VirtualHost>
```

and then add the host name your your `/etc/hosts` file:

`127.0.0.1 companysite.local`

Now, youll also have to create the folder structure and set the permissions appropriately. the User/Group for apache is `www` so after you have created the dir structure:

```
sudo chown -R www:www /home/web
sudo chmod -R +a "www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit"
sudo chmod -R +a "YOUR_USER_NAME allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I'm sure virtual hosting is what I need, but I don't think the above code will work. The above config is essentially what I have on my work computer and on the live server. However, I can't put my root there on a Mac. Hence my problem.